# Brand new laptop li-ion battery has 74% capacity, should I return it? What can I do?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery

I've only had this battery for maybe three days. I think it might have hit 100% once... and it hasn't since. It's been dropping... 94%, then 92%, now 91%... I know that you're only supposed to charge a battery to 100% once in a while for calibration... I don't know why I'm obsessing about this 100% thing.

I have the opportunity to return the battery and get another one albeit losing money.

I've tried on three different operating systems, debian, linux mint, ubuntu... Looking at acpi the last "full capacity" was 7744mAh out of the 10400mAh this seems bad for a "new" battery according to the seller.

Should I get a refund/get a replacement?

What are some more things that I can try?

I've dropped the power all the way until the battery dies, I've killed it through bios as well, and leaving it charge for half a day, it only reached 91% or so... I think I hit 93% once today.

Answer (score 0):

In roughly decreasing order of likelihood:

1. On my laptop there is a **BIOS option to only charge to 80%** rather than 100%. This is supposed to improve longevity, which in my case I believe it has. Have you checked for such an option?
2. It could be a **refurbished** one if the model has been on the market for a while. Is there a sticker on the battery or a note on your receipt to indicate refurbished parts?
3. QA isn't perfect - sometimes **faulty equipment** slips through. You may simply have been unlucky.
4. **Non-original** batteries can vary greatly in quality. How is the battery branded? Does it look like it's been tampered with?
5. There may be an **ACPI bug.** Unlikely, but has to be said.

I'd try returning it, but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am going to return it. No options in bios unfortunately. Just sucks, I hate waiting, luckily I can get money back. Will try another one.

Comment: Another possibility might be old stock - Batteries loose significant capacity over time just sitting on the shelf unused.   It very much depends on the storage condition, but 20% per year for a fully charged battery is typical.

Comment: Now it's at 83% that's probably why these batteries are junk, surprising the rate in capacity drop happening in a matter of days not months/years